Deploy script to anvil node foundry
Is it possible to simulate a contract deployment, using a script, to an anvil node but by specifying the localhost in the script itself instead of a flag on the CLI command?
Instead of this:
forge script script/NFT.s.sol:MyScript --fork-url http://localhost:8545 --broadcast

..., something like this:
Counter.s.sol

vm.rpcUrl("http://localhost:8545"); //<--- this only deploys it, but it doesn't simulate it

CLI
forge script script/Counter.s.sol:CounterScript --broadcast

